# Web8: Colud not connect to ImportExport service on Content Manager Server

Tags: web8.5, content-porter-web8

First time I installed the SDLWeb8 Content Porter and try to connect the CMS and got this error.

any one have solution for content porting  connection issue.

[image]

Comment: anything in the CP logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please update log information? But in most of the cases this type of  error occurred because of wrong domain name.

In Content Porter you need to provide the **protocol**, **port**, **name** and **description**. So no need to add the http:// or https:// in your server name again.

For example say your cms url is http://cms.testserver.com ,then entering cms.testserver.com is enough as a server name.